# Ruby on Rails store code to execute in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, web-scraping, eval

I have a model `Shop` in my database which sum up everything I want to know about a shop (`name`, `url`, `price`)

I would like some advise on what is the best way to deal with my situation.
Basically, what I want is to scrap website (which don't have API) to get the price displayed on the page.

For example, let's say that I want to get the price from this [page](https://store.motogp.com/fr/pilotes/no46-rossi-109/3497_tshirt-officiel-yamaha-rossi-vr46.html), every time a user visit the page X and the price from this [page](https://store.motogp.com/fr/motogptm-176/motogp-vintage--177/3071_veste-en-cuir.html) every time he comes to the page Y and so on with 1000+ pages.

The `Shops` in my database would be :

```
Shop #1 : {:name => "Tshirt", :url => "XXXXX", :price => "PRICE_FROM_THE_URL"}
Shop #2 : {:name => "Veste", :url => "XXXXX", :price => "PRICE_FROM_THE_URL"}
```

I see two options to update the price every time a user ask it :

1. Store the code to update the price in the database and evaluate it every time it is needed. Something like, adding a column `code` and do `price = eval(Shop.code)`
2. Call an action on my model according to the shop ID. Something like a switch case according to `self.id`

I tried both options. Both works as expected, but my concerns is that option #1 looks like the "ugly" one but easier to maintain, while option #2 is not well fitted if you have 1000+ shops to record and every one has a different scrapping method. I will end up with thousands of code line and it will become impossible to understand.

Comment: take a look at [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)

Comment: @PiotrKruczek My question is not about how to scrap

Comment: Another thing to consider is that you do not run these other sites (assumption) which means if they change their page your scrape code will fail. As far as the best way to go about it i would not eval the code. Honestly I think modularizing the specific methods for each site would be best where each shop would have it's own implementation of something like `get_price` while it seems like it will create a lot of small files it will make managing changes far easier in the future and will isolate a shop. Also those look like items not shops

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes I am aware of that but it is an issue that I will solve later on ;)

Comment: Maybe have the scripts elsewhere and store something per shop that says which script to use?

Comment: *"#1 looks like the "ugly" one but easier to maintain"* - why is code in a database easier do maintain?

Comment: @Stefan because each entry have its own code directly associated, I must have said "easier to understand". You don't have to find somewhere in the code, at the right ID, the code that will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri lets you scrape content by [css selectors](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri#synopsis).
Knowing that, considen following design guidelines:

1. Create a model with selectors for specified shop, name it: `ShopSelectorGroup` (it can also be created as ActiveRecord model, to store selectors in database).

   ```
   class ShopSelectorGroup
     attr_accessor: :price_selector, :other_selector, :shop_name
   end
   ```
2. Then create a class `Scraper` which will be configured by injecting an instance of `ShopSelectorGroup` class.

   ```
   require 'nokogiri'
   require 'open-uri'

   class Scraper
     def initialize(selector_group)
       @selector_group = selector_group
     end

     def scrape(url)
       open(url) do |content|                        
         Nokogiri::HTML(content).css(@selector_group.price_selector).each do |data|
           yield data
        end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. Use it as follows:

   ```
   selector_group = ShopSelectorGroup.new
   selector_group.price_selector = 'span.price'
   # or when used as ActiveRecord model
   # selector_group = ShopSelectorGroup.findByShopName('MyShop')

   scraper = Scraper.new(selector_group)
   scraper.scrape(url) do |data|
     p data
     # or persist data in database
   end
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If `ShopSelectorGroup` is not an active record object you will need to build an initialize method to handle the instance variable assignment. If it is you have built the `selector_group` in the example incorrectly as `selector` is not an attribute. I would suggest revising before others come along and downvote this answer. Also would it not make more sense to create the selector group inside `Scraper::initialize` instead?

Comment: Thanks for spotting the lack of initialize method. I've corrected the code. When it goes to initializing scraper_group, injecting it is a key, because we want the scraper to behave defferently based on injected object. That is scrapping by different selectors, according to shop.

Comment: Yes I understood the context my point was the only item in `Scraper` that is set during `initialize` is the instance_variable `@selector_group` (which should always be a `ShopSelectorGroup`). So why not instead of worrying about if `initialize` is given a `ShopSelectorGroup` just allow `initialize` to accept the same arguments as `ShopSelectorGroup::initialize` and then just `@selector_group = ShopSelectorGroup.new(selector_group_args)` this way you know it is always a `ShopSelectorGroup` (obviously I am suggesting that this would be outside of AR)

Comment: Decoupling initialization of those two objects will make this solution more flexible. In code, in one context we can initialize `ShopSelectorGroup` on the fly i other context we can load it from database or we can inject defferent objects, that has `prece_selector` method (it doesn't always have to be a `ShopSelectorGroup`).